# Calculating 16-bit integer value from two 8-bit integers?

Tags: python, integer, hex

To illustrate what I mean: In a hex editor I have `8C 01` which is `396` little-endian. The data I'm working with is a tuple with two separate 8-bit integers `i = (140, 1)`.

To calculate the 16-bit value my first approach was to simply multiply the 2nd integer by 255 then add the first. However this method is simply wrong as it does not give the correct value (due to my lack of knowledge). Can anyone provide a better (possibly Pythonic) approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to multiply it with **256** (2<sup>8</sup>). So the function would be something like:

```
def pack (tup) :
    return 256*tup[1]+tup[0]
```

or perform a [bitwise shift](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators), which makes more sense when working with bits:

```
def pack(tup) :
    return (tup[1]<<8)|tup[0]
```

here `<<` means you place the value of `tup[1]` eight positions to the left. The pipe (`|`) means you perform an OR-operation. This is reasonable if you enforce the values in the tuple are less than `256` and can - at least theoretically - result in some speedup.

## More generic

In case your tuple has an arbitrary length (for instance three, four, or more elements), you can define a more generic function:

```
def pack(tup) :
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(tup)) :
        sum |= tup[i]<<(i<<3)
    return sum
```

Here `<<3` is used as a shortcut to multiplying with `8`, so an equivalent function would be:

```
def pack(tup) :
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(tup)) :
        sum |= tup[i]<<(8*i)
    return sum
```

Or written out, it is something like:

```
tup[0]|(tup[1]<<8)|(tup[2]<<16)|(...)
```

Comment: I like the latter approach but just to consolidate my understanding would you mind writing an example for 32-bit number using a 4-tuple of 8-bits?

Comment: Well it comes down on multiplying with powers of `256`. So for three items you can calculate it as `65536*tup[2]+256*tup[1]+tup[0]`, or `(tup[2]<<16)|(tup[1]<<8)|tup[0]`. The function uses `<<3` as a substitute to multiplying with `8`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I assume you meant something like `tup[0]|(tup[1]<<3)|(tup[2]<<6)|(tup[3]<<9)|(...)` in the last code snippet?  For some reason my edit to that effect contravenes this site's edit rules and was rejected.

Comment: @OutstandingBill: Hi, no, it is `tup[0]|(tup[1]<<8)|...` so with hops of eight. The `<<3` is applie dto the `i` in the first code example, to multiply it with eight (multiplying with eight is the same as shifting three places to the left).

Answer (score 6):

You should multiply by 256...

```
>>> i[1]*256 + i[0]
396
```

There is a Python way using `struct` module, but not necessary in such a simple case.

```
>>> from struct import pack, unpack
>>> unpack('<H', pack('BB', *i))[0]
396
```